# I'm trying to use some data i pulled from a php database as information in a clickable SVG picture (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
require_once('dbconn.php');

$arm = "SELECT problem, description, reason, reg_date FROM body_arm";
$result = $conn->query($arm);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " " . $row["problem"].

         " - " . $row["description"].
         " - reason: " . $row["reason"].
         " - TIMESTAMP:" . $row["reg_date"].
              "<br/>";

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>


<!--

Here I have some code for the SVG


-->

    <script>


    window.onload = function () {

        const pieces = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
        for (var i = 0; pieces.length; i++) {
            let _piece = pieces[i];
            _piece.onclick = function(t) {

                if (t.target.getAttribute('data-position') != null) 
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = t.target.getAttribute('data-position');


              if (t.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-position') != null) 
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = t.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-position');

            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

- I have tried to use the function ob_get_contents, couldn't really get it working.
- I have tried to echo the php variable to javascript like: var val = "";

As I'm starting to understand I can't really find the php variable in javascript and need to find a way around that or maybe use something like node.js to open a connection to the server with something closer to javascript? I'm a beginner by the way!

Comment: Take a look at AJAX. That might have some answer for your question

Comment: Thanks for the help sureshprasanna70! I kinda got it working using "json_encode", but now it only outputs one row. Gonna take a look at an AJAX solution too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution I found was json_encode!

$example_array_variable = json_encode($example);
//Doing this in the PHP.

//Then later in the JavaScript decode it.

echo json_encode($example_array_variable);

Eureka!!